# How to manipulate access_token from spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webclient

I am trying to use WebClient to invoke an endpoint from an other server. The invocation works, I also get an access_token from the server, but the access_token has the wrong value. The value I need is in the id_token.

```
{
    "access_token": "0Ad5zZycgr0moxsK8v1J_J4nIYR",
    "scope": "openid",
    "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJraWQiOiJlR3hJZjhQbU9LSmVxTi9qU...",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 59
}
```

I could not find a way to access the id_token. The other problem is: even if I get the id_token how can I write the value of the id_token into the access_token.

Is there a way in spring boot / spring security to access the id_token and to write it in the access_token

Comment: Some code would be useful here. Not sure how you are using Spring security here but there is a way to provide custom WebClient and customize request/response.